# Why does substring expansion [ test="-efoo"; echo ${test:0:2} ] fail?

Tags: bash, parameter

On Linux Mint, using bash..

```
test="-ffoo"; echo ${test:0:2}
```

works outputting the first two characters

but

```
test="-efoo"; echo ${test:0:2}
```

fails, with apparently null output.

I'm thinking the form of this is

```
${parameter:offset:length}
```

I know enough that parameter characters cannot be `*@#?-$!0_`

but `$test` is the parameter - surely its contents can be anything? I guess `-e` is triggering something shell-like but why..

Comment: Strongly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: This is more about getting the correct answer than the diff between echo and printf. [test="-efoo"; answer=${test:0:2}; echo $answer ] seems to have the same problem with answer not seeing the correct result from ${test:0:2}

Comment: methinks /user/ilkkachu has OCD. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run

```
test="-efoo"; echo ${test:0:2}
```

`echo` is run with the argument `-e`, which in some `echo` implementations including the `echo` builtin command of most `bash` deployments, is a valid option and is thus “swallowed”.

[Use `printf` instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/86440):

```
test="-efoo"; printf %s\\n "${test:0:2}"
```

Comment: Why then does this have the same problem? > test="-efoo"; answer=${test:0:2}; echo $answer

Comment: You’re still passing -e to echo...